# PHP File Upload file the same size

Tags: html, css

I have coded my own file upload script for a profile where the user can set their photo. And my image code is like this:

```
<img style="border-radius:100%" src="<?php echo $config['url']; ?>/photos/<?php echo GetVar($_SESSION['user']['id'], "avatar"); ?>" width="50" alt="avatar" />
```

And when i try to do 100% border radius with the new photo it goes too wide? I think this is because the width and height of the new photo isn't the same if this is the case how can I block this? Or if anyone else thinks it's something different please say so.

This is the default picture and it works fine with the border radius:
[image]

And this is the new one uploaded using the upload script but it's wide:
[image]

Comment: I love how egotistical users love to downvote question for no apparent reason and don't even bother to give an explanation, this is a valid question, the answer below should work for you...

Answer (score 0):

Make the image a background set to cover of a fixed size div then apply your css to make it a circle from there.

```
<style>
  .avatar{
    border-radius:100%;
    background-size:cover;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
  }
</style>

<div style="background:url(<?php echo $config['url']; ?>);" class="avatar">

</div>
```